# Don't understand Yarn check warning

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

When I run `yarn check` I got this warning:

```
 warning "\u001b[2mchokidar#\u001b[22mfsevents#node-pre-gyp@^0.6.29"
 could be deduped from "0.6.32" to "node-pre-gyp@0.6.32"
```

Would someone please help me understand this?

- I don't know what does the word `deduped` mean.
- Why there are so many rubbish characters in the warning message?
- What should I do to solve this warning?

Many thanks!

Comment: Data deduplication ... dedupe := to de-duplicate (I admit that I had to consult google for that).

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I also googled that but as a newbie I just want to double check :D

Comment: For the warning - I don't know nothing about yarn, but it looks to me as if the tool found duplicate dependencies. For now I'd ignore. There is a reported issue for these warnings. Enjoy! https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2287

Comment: @Andreas_D I do enjoy this issue. Laughed out while reading this lol

Comment: The "rubbish characters" are terminal formatting [escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code): `\u001b[2m` means "faint" (light grey), and `\u001b[22m` means normal color. (That they're, um, escaping into the visible message would seem to be a yarn bug.) So the message is actually `warning "chokidar#fsevents#node-pre-gyp@^0.6.29" could be deduped from "0.6.32" to "node-pre-gyp@0.6.32"` -- with the "chokidar#" part meant to be de-emphasized. (Though I actually came here looking for the answer to your third question.)

Answer (score 11):

It looks like that your `yarn.lock` file contains a duplicated entry for the package `node-pre-gyp` at the version `0.6.32`.

You can do the following steps:

1. Delete the `yarn.lock` file.
2. Reinstall the packages to generate a new yarn.lock `yarn install`.
3. Run again the `yarn check` command.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I can only hope it's safe to ignore.

Comment: I'm pretty sure deleting your yarn.lock file and calling `yarn install` will CHANGE the versions of packages you're using... this might **not** be what you want.

Comment: For me this changes the installed versions without fixing the problem. More concerning perhaps is that this answer got a lot of upvotes, which means it must work for those people. How can something like this work for some people and do something totally different for others?